# Dot Net : Wrapper class to create image from SWF file

Tags: .net, flash

Is there any wrapper class available in .Net so that I can create an image from a flash movie(swf file) ?

I know there is something called FFMPEG, but it's an exe. Since I am not going to deploy my application on a dedicated server, I cannot put an exe file in the server. Are there any classes available which embed the functionality of this FFMPEG, so that I can directly use it ?

My ultimate requirement is to produce Image from SWF file. This is not a screen capture, but getting an image from swf files stored in a particular folder in the server.

Comment: Do you mean a screen capture at a point in time during playback?

Comment: Err....not screen capture, but "Flash capture," i.e. capture a frame from the Flash player?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in .Net Framework directly. You would have to find a library from someone or write it yourself....